# Multilevel LI cascades ONCLICK event

Tags: html, onclick, html-lists

I am looking for a way to create a multilevel tree with onclick events in each node.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="tree">
   <ul id="UL1" onclick="alert('LEVEL1');">
      <li id="LI1">
         LEVEL1
         <ul id="UL2" onclick="alert('LEVEL2');">
            <li id="LI2">
               LEVEL2
               <ul id="UL3" onclick="alert('LEVEL3');">            
                  <li id="LI3">
                     LEVEL3
                     <ul id="UL3" onclick="alert('LEVEL4');">
                        <li id="LI4" >LEVEL4                        
                     </ul>                  
               </ul>
         </ul>      
   </ul>
</div>
```

The purpose is that if user clicks on the LEVEL4 (for example) he gets an alert for LEVEL4 only. The problem is that the alert is cascaded and when clicking on some specific level i get all the inheritance alerts:

- clicking on LEVEL4 --> alerts for LEVEL4, LEVEL3, LEVEL2 and LEVEL1
- clicking on LEVEL3 --> alerts for LEVEL3, LEVEL2 and LEVEL1
- etc...

I am looking to have the alert only for the corresponding level that I clicked instead of inheriting the rest of upper levels...

Is there any easy way to achieve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation with unobtrusive code instead of inline.

Attach the `eventlistener` to your parent element and use the `event` object's `target` to identify the element which triggered the event.

For example:

```js
// Your parent element
var div = document.getElementById("tree");

// Attach the eventlistener to the parent element
div.addEventListener('click', dosomething);

// Use the target from the event object that is passed to the handler
function dosomething(e) {
 console.log("You clicked " + e.target.id); 
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
   <ul id="UL1" >
      <li id="LI1">
         LEVEL1
         <ul id="UL2" >
            <li id="LI2">
               LEVEL2
               <ul id="UL3" >            
                  <li id="LI3">
                     LEVEL3
                     <ul id="UL3" >
                        <li id="LI4" >LEVEL4                        
                     </ul>                  
               </ul>
         </ul>      
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abhi,Thanks! that was what I was looking for. The problem now is that I am using a jquery library (fancytree) to be able to transform the ul/li structure into a nice tree view...   At some point the library sets the display property to NONE for all the UL, and then I think is where I am losing the event handling... Nothing is shown when the display property is set to none.... Is there any relation between having the parent element as diplay:none and assigning an event to it?

Comment: @byle.05 that shouldn't be a problem. You can ask a new question with a minimum reproducible example. That will help.

Comment: Thanks Abhi, I was finally able to sort it out. The problem is that the fancy tree library replaces my UL/LI structure with their own and my ID's are lost. I have slightly modified the library to inherit those Ids and now works perfectly :)